# How to slide up a Fragment in android application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a Mainactivity in my `Android Studio` application. 
If for an example information are missing, I would like to slide up a (dialog box like) `Panel`, which shall not have full screen size. Lets assume the lower third of the full screen..

When user entered missing information, this `Panel` can slide back down and disappear..

[Example](http://blog.neteril.org/wp-content/uploads/framelayout/sliding-panel.gif)

Since I am new to android development, I do not know how to do this?

Comment: will android snackbar do what you want?

Comment: @penduDev Can I place other widgets (like editText or ubttons) on a snackbar? It shall only show up, when user information is missin, not on "mouse move over" , possible?

Comment: Fragments are for full UI panes, such as master-detail layout on tablets, or full screen. If it's just to show a user error, use Snackbar or ViewStub

Comment: @RalfWickum You can add text and actions to SnackBar. The good thing is that if follows Material Design guidelines

Comment: @LouisCAD I am intereseted in adding buttons / imagebuttons.

Comment: Could you add a mockup of what you are looking for in your question?

Comment: @LouisCAD This is a good example: http://blog.neteril.org/wp-content/uploads/framelayout/sliding-panel.gif

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [SlidingPaneLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) or [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel), or something similar.